# VBA line spacing Powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

i would like to write a makro that adjust the line spacing (Screenshot) in VBA for PowerPoint 2013. I thought this is not a problem but i can't find the right command.

Many THX!!!

[image: Screenshot PowerPoint 2013]

This are my first draft commands (both are working) but not adjust the line spacing

```
Sub Zeilenabstand()


     ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
     ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.SpaceWithin = 1

End Sub
```

Comment: Please show us your current code.
Ein Beispiel bitte.

Comment: I think you need something like this: http://superuser.com/questions/241150/default-line-spacing-in-powerpoint-200707

Comment: @meck373, did you ever figure this out? I have the same problem.

Comment: @commodore73 - Nope :( So if you figure it out, please add it here.

Comment: @meck373 I gave up, just set .ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore, .ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter, and .ParagraphFormat.SpaceWithin to values that seem to work for my purposes. Unfortunate that M$ removed the record macro feature that could have answered questions like this.

Comment: @commodore73 :)

Comment: I think "LineRuleWithin" is what you're looking for [DETAILS HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.paragraphformat.linerulewithin)
Use this in combination with your "SpaceWithin" code.